# Mariadb Scans all partitions in timestamp column

Tags: sql, hash, mariadb, partitioning

I have a table Partitioned by:

`HASH(timestamp DIV 43200 )`

When I perform this query

```
SELECT max(id) 
  FROM messages 
 WHERE timestamp BETWEEN 1581708508 AND 1581708807
```

it scans all partitions while both numbers `1581708508` & `1581708807`& numbers between them are in the same partition, how can I make it to scan only that partition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can determine that individual partition by using modular arithmetic

`MOD(<formula which's argument of hash function>,<number of partitions>)`

assuming you have 2 partitions

```
CREATE TABLE messages(ID int, timestamp int)
PARTITION BY HASH( timestamp DIV 43200 )
PARTITIONS 2;
```

look up partition names by

```
SELECT CONCAT( 'p',MOD(timestamp DIV 43200,2)) AS partition_name, timestamp 
  FROM messages;
```

and determine the related partition name for the value 1581708508 of timestamp column (assume `p1`). Then Use

```
SELECT MAX(id) 
  FROM messages PARTITION(p1)
```

to get all the records only in the partition `p1` without need of a `WHERE` condition such as

`WHERE timestamp BETWEEN 1581708508 AND 1581708807`

Btw, all partitions might be listed through

```
SELECT * 
  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PARTITIONS 
 WHERE table_name='messages'
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=4e81f4e8aaf37e0a4f1d68c3ee3acc4a)</kbd>

Comment: Isn't there a way that mariadb detects the needed partitions automatically? Because the timestamp range that I provide defers and may be it covers one partition and maybe once it covers 3 partitions, when the difference between those two timestamps that I provided in the where clasue it 10 seconds it scans only one partition but when the difference is 200 seconds it scans all partitions while the whole 200 seconds still are in the same partition

Comment: @MohammadAminGhaseminia I'd like you to suggest to use dynamic SQL as `SET @prt=(SELECT DISTINCT CONCAT( 'p',MOD(timestamp DIV 43200,2)) AS partition_name 
              FROM messages m
             WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 0 FROM messages WHERE timestamp = 1581708508 AND timestamp=m.timestamp));
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT * FROM messages PARTITION(?) ' USING @prt;` but unfortunately it doesn't work for table or partition names whereas works for parameter binding witihn a WHERE Clause.

Comment: @MohammadAminGhaseminia - Hash partition can do partition pruning only if you use `=` in the `WHERE`.  See what I added to my Answer.

Answer (score 1):

You have discovered one of the reasons why `PARTITION BY HASH` is useless.

In your situation, the Optimizer sees the range (`BETWEEN`) and says "punt, I'll just scan all the partitions".

That is, "partition pruning" does not work when the `WHERE` clause involves a range and you are using `PARTITION BY HASH`.  `PARTITION BY RANGE`, on the other hand, *may* be able to prune.  But... What's the advantage?  It does not make the query any faster.

I have found *only* four uses for partitioning:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint .  It sounds like your application does not fit any of those cases.

That particular query would best be done without partitioning.  Instead have a non-partitioned table with this 'composite' index:

```
INDEX(timestamp, id)
```

It must scan all the rows to discover the `MAX(id)`, but with this index, it is

- Scanning only the 2-column index
- Not touching any rows outside the timestamp range.

Hence it will be as fast as possible.  Even if `PARTITION BY HASH` were smart enough to do the desired pruning, it would *not* run any faster.

In particular, when you ask for a range on the Partition key, such as with `WHERE timestamp BETWEEN 1581708508 AND 1581708807`, the execution looks in *all* partitions for the desired rows.  This is one of the major failings of Hash.  Even if it could realize that only Partition is needed, it would be no faster than simply using the index I suggest.